# Few queries on Facebook developer for android

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android app, that uses wireless enabled health sensors to be monitored from an android devices. Since, I am new to both web and Facebook application development, I was wondering if I could:

1. Use Facebook as a platform (without using any other websites), for sending all health data from mobile directly to Facebook.
2. Use those data, received from mobile devices and plot graphs, charts and send notification to friends based on those data.
3. I want to do everything in Facebook. Which programming language do I need to use?

Since, I am noob on this please forgive me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say that I understand what it is you're after, I'll try to answer as best as I can/understand:

1. You can send data to facebook of course, from any device that has internet connection, but data that is sent to facebook is being shared with others, it's not a hosting service, the whole purpose is to share the data with friends.  Is that what you want?
2. If you need to compute and perform calculations on the data then you'll probably (if the calculation is not very simple) need to do that on your own servers, you can then create those graphs and present them in a facebook application.
3. Define "doing things in facebook".  Facebook do host your application, you need to have your own server(s) which host your files, heck even if your application is completely static, that is just html/js/css/images, you still need to host is somewhere. Facebook is just an interface to your application.

I hope I helped with this and made things more clear for you, if you still have things you need/want to understand, please explain your situation better.

Comment: My application will just send numbers, that can be presented as graph. Calculations are fairly simple ones. I want Facebook to receive data from phones and then present it in graphs and things like nike+. Will I still need to host it on my own server? Doing thing means

Comment: Yeah, you'll need your own server(s) to persist the data and then render it into graphs and what not. As I said, facebook is just an interface.